# Infinite-dimensional manifold $ΩG$ of loops and the complex projective $n$-space

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, at.algebraic-topology, gauge-theory, infinite-dimensional-manifolds

In a review seminar today, I heard the speaker takes the below for granted, but I have no enough background

"Yang-Mills (YM) instantons in 4D can be naturally identified with (i.e. have the same parameter space as) the instantons in 2D for the theory in which the complex projective $n$-space $CP^n$ is replaced by the infinite- dimensional manifold $ΩG$ of loops on the structure group $G$. Such a theory is not as bizarre as it appears because $ΩG$ is well-known to share most of the important properties of $CP^n$ and it arises naturally in many contexts.

So my questions are that

> 1. What are the well-known properties/relations relating infinite- dimensional manifold $ΩG$ to complex projective $n$-space $CP^n$? (of on the structure group $G$ is which? SU(n)?)
> 2. Is that 
>      $$\text{an instanton number=1 of 4D SU($n$)  YM theory,} \tag{eq.1}$$
>
> maps to
>
> $$\text{the instanton number=1 of 2D $CP^n$,} \tag{eq.2}$$
>
> maps to
>
> $$\text{the instanton number=1 of}$$ 
>   $$\text{2D infinite-dimensional manifold $ΩG$ of loops on the structure group $G$} \tag{eq.3}$$
>   (with $G$=SU($n$)?)
>
> What are the precise maps between the instanton numbers in (1),(2),(3)? And how to prove them?

p.s. I understand eq.(1),(2), but I do not understand the model in eq.(3) well-enough.

I know a Ref: Instantons In Two-dimensions And Four-dimensions, 1984 - 15 pages Commun.Math.Phys. 93 (1984) 437-451, M.F. Atiyah

Comment: $\Omega G$ is basically the best infinite-dimensional manifold out there, ignoring cases that are colimits of finite-dimensional things (like $\mathbb{CP}^\infty$)

Comment: @David Roberts, thanks what do you mean by the "best"? what is the choice of $G$? many thanks!